# Filter in pre (find) hook Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to perform a query that filters an array from another document, to mention something about the structure, I try to populate the document based on the specified product and store id, so that it doesn't bring the other data from the array but in this case I understand that I can't access the document fields while in the middleware, I'm reading the documentation but I still learning concepts

```
bUnitSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  
  this.populate({
    path: "menuItem.product",

    select: {
      "storeId.$": 1,
    },
    match: {
      "storeId.store": "62a811d1af67f5415770f297",
      
    },
  });

  next();
});
```

any guide would be of excellent help

I try something like this

```
bUnitSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  
  this.populate({
    path: "menuItem.product",

    select: {
      "storeId.$": 1,
    },
    match: {
      
       *//here im trying to do something like this*
      *"storeid.store": bUnitSchema.menuItem.store*
    },
  });

  next();
});
```

but give me

> store not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve it, i use a post hook :

```js
bUnitSchema.post(/^find/, async function (docs) {
  for (let doc of docs) {
    for (let store of doc.menuItem) {
      await doc.populate({
        path: "menuItem.product",
        select: {
          image: 1,
          imagePath: 1,
          plateFor: 1,
          description: 1,
          name: 1,
          _id: 1,
          "storeId.$": 1,
        },
        match: {
          "storeId.store": store.store,
        },
      });
    }
  }
});
```

If anyone has a better idea, it would be appreciated.